# Val defined in package object unaccessable in other classes

Tags: scala

I have the following package object with a `val` declared in it

```
package au.com.someproject.protocol

package object helpers {
  val etcdRoot = "someproject.com.au"
}
```

This package object is declared as part of an API, when I import the API into another project and I try to access the variable I meet with the following error

```
[error] /home/user/git/company/project/project-agent/src/main/scala/au/com/someproject/project_agent/cluster/StatusMonitor.scala:52: not found: value etcdRoot
[error]       etcdClient.setKey(s"$etcdRoot/kumo/peers/${systemCluster.selfAddress.host.get}", systemCluster.selfAddress.port.get.toString, new Some(40.seconds))
```

I'm importing the variable like so, how I would except it should be done

```
import au.com.someproject.protocol.helpers._
```

But yet I get the error, is there something I am doing wrong with the declaration or importing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your importing is valid. Can you check the dependency (inspect the JAR file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's usually a catch with package objects, they have to be manually placed inside the package folder, meaning I would expect your directory structure to look like this before the import would work.

```
src/main/scala/au/com/someproject/protocol/helpers/helpers.scala
```

And inside the `helpers/`, you define your `package object`. Sometimes you are tempted to have it like the below:

```
src/main/scala/au/com/someproject/protocol/helpers.scala
```

The above doesn't actually define the `package object` on the `helpers` package, you need to follow the specific directory structure and manually define the `package` before you define the `package object` inside it.

Comment: Running `java tf` on the archive shows that the package object class is in the right package directory `au/com/someproject/protocol/helpers/package.class`

Comment: @LiamHaworth, perhaps, is there a chance you could double check the source code though?

Comment: This seems to be a strange one, the API package consists of classes built from Protobuf messages which live under `au.com.someproject.protocol`. It seems that when I have the `helpers` and `exceptions` packages under `protocol` that I run into import issues. Moving the package object under the root `au.com.someproject` it seems to work now o_O